# Abertura de arquivo via metodo Load jquery

Tags: jquery

Nem sei por onde começar vais vou ter simplificar! Estou tentando criar uma pagina de administração, onde os dados tem que ser enviados via metodo $.post e e receber via $.get, mais quando tento ler o arquivo php onde se encontra o script para leitura dos dados, pelo metodo load ele n abre!!

Codigo Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alerta();
        Ler();
    });

    function Ler(){
setTimeout("$('#pagina').load('http://www.teste.dev/views/categoria/mostrar.php', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });", 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Você analisou o erro que dá? Tente visualizar o debuger do seu navegador, para ver onde está se perdendo, talvez seja um probleminha de caminho relativo.

Comment: Como assim "os dados tem que ser enviados via metodo $.post e e receber via $.get"??

Comment: Oi, @Sam, fui ver sua edição porque estava dando problema num plugin meu pro site, o `<pre>` que vc colocou faz o Syntax Highlight não funcionar. . . . . Só precisa usar HTML aqui em casos especiais `sup,sub,kbd`, o resto é melhor em puro Markdown. Dois `enter` fazem um parágrafo `<p>`, dois espaços em branco forçam o `<br>`, código é só aplicar 4 espaços para fazer o `<pre>`. Vide [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1297/201)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual o erro que é retornado?

O seu caminho absoluto está correcto?

A função "alerta()" existe no seu script?

Experimente alterar o seu código:

```
function Ler(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#pagina').load('http://www.teste.dev/views/categoria/mostrar.php',function(){ 
            $('#loaderImage').hide(); 
        });
    }), 1000);
}
```

Comment: Realmente o problema estava no caminho absoluto, depois de verificar o log do navegador, notei que ele n encontrava o arquivo especificado..